# Using cases with jubilare

Tags: grammar-choice, verbs

I heard [a song](https://libera.org.uk/music/libera-cd/) using the phrase *jubilate Deo*, and it seems that this phrase appears in [a psalm](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0060%3Abook%3DPsalms%3Achapter%3D99%3Averse%3D2) as well.
I assume the *Deo/Domino* is a dative.
On the other hand, the [L&S entry for *jubilare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=jubilo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) also mentions the accusative usage *me jubilat*.

So, it seems that I can use *jubilare* with accusative or dative.
What is the difference between the two cases?
Perhaps *Marcum iubilo* would mean "I call out to Marcus" and *Marco iubilo* "I shout in joy for Marcus" — I would like to have more than my guess.
I haven't managed to find a comparison, and the cited dictionary makes no explicit mention of cases whatsoever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb and suggest that this is a calque from the Septuagint translation of the Psalms. [*Iubilare*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23iubil) is very rare (by my count, less than 10 occurrences) and does not have any attested uses with the dative or ablative.

The Greek, however, is quite clear:

> **᾿Αλαλάξατε τῷ κυρίῳ**, πᾶσα ἡ γῆ (Ps 99 (100): 1)

[*ἀλαλάζω*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)lala%2Fzw) can be used with the accusative (*what* they are shouting about) or dative (*to whom* they raise a cry): the latter usage is seen in the *Anabasis*:

> ἐπεὶ δ᾽ ἐπαιάνισαν καὶ ἡ σάλπιγξ ἐφθέγξατο, ἅμα τε **τῷ Ἐνυαλίῳ ἠλέλιξαν**. (Xen *Ana* 5.2)
>
> <sup>Then, they sang and the trumpet sounded, and at the same time **they raised a shout to Enyalius.**</sup>

One fact worth noting is that the Psalms, which were such an integral part of the liturgy, were firmly engrained in the minds of early Latin-speaking Christians before Jerome undertook his translation. As a result, the Vulgate follows the *Vetus Latina* very closely, often with somewhat confusing results. The *Vetus Latina* (if I am not mistaken) used the Septuagint as its primary source text, so it seems reasonable that they copied the Greek syntax above with the most plausible substitute for *ἀλαλάζω*: *iubilo*.

Pius XII commissioned an updated translation of the psalms that follows the Hebrew with less awkward syntax. Its translation is slightly different:

> Exsultate Domino, omnes terrae.

[*Exsulto*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dexsulto), as seen in the linked L&S entry, often takes the ablative (alone or with *in*).

In short: ***iubilo* + dat./abl. is not classically attested and may just be a Latin calque on a Greek construction**, though it is readily understood.

Comment: BTW, I'm aware that the *Vetus Latina* is not a monolithic translation, and my statement about its relation to the LXX is based on vague memories. I appreciate any corrections/clarifications!

Comment: Your speculation looks well-based and convincing to me. But though I take the point that you find no other examples of _jubilo_ governing a dative or ablative, can you explain why _Jubilate Deo_ itself, certainly familiar since the mid-fourth century, cannot provide an adequate precedent for anyone who wishes to use the verb?

Comment: @TomCotton I didn't quite say that: the fact that it isn't "classically attested" is a big deal to some, a non-issue for others. In fact, many of the "idiosyncracies" of medieval Latin are direct results of translation choices like these, to a much greater extent than how many phrases in modern English are influenced by the KJV.

Comment: Jerome’s “iubilate Deo” could however also be seen as a perfectly literal translation of הָרִיעוּ לַיהוָה “make a joyful noise unto the LORD”, with the preposition “la” rendered (as usual) by the Latin dative.

Comment: @fdb That sounds about right, though the *Vetus Latina* primarily was translated from the Septuagint, which itself was a pretty literal translation from the Hebrew. Jerome followed the *Vetus Latina* very closely for the Psalms, since they were already so well known.

Answer (score 3):

*Jubilate Deo* is the opening to Psalm 100 :

*Jubilate Deo omnis terra! Quia veniet tibi salvator!(bis) Montes et colles humiliabuntur Et erit in die illa lux magna, Ecce veniet in nubibus coeli*. . .

It's usually translated as 'Rejoice in the Lord, all ye Lands!', and there is a well-known English hymn, called 'The Old Hundredth', which has 'All people that on Earth do dwell / Sing to the Lord with cheerful voice . . .'

I think in the present case that you might regard *Deo* as either ablative ('Rejoice in') or dative (sing / shout out to), just as you wish. The accusative is also used in the sense of 'hail', or 'call out to', for which Smith's Latin-English gives an example, *jubilare aliquem*.

Comment: To avoid possible confusion, I ought to add that this is Ps. 100 in the _Book of Divine Worship_. In the Vulgate it is no. 99.

Comment: It is numbered as "100" in the Hebrew Bible and the English KJV; in the LXX and Vulgata it is numbered as "99".